# Android: the bind value at index 1 is null error

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite, android-contacts, android-background

I am developing an application in which i am running a background service as:

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactService.class));
```

In Menifest:

```
<service android:name=".ContactService" ></service>
```

And the service code is as follows:

```
public class ContactService extends Service {
    private int mContactCount;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Get contact count at start of service
        mContactCount = getContactCount();
        this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);
        Cursor curval = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (curval != null && curval.getCount() > 0) {
            curval.getCount();
        }
        curval.close();
    }

    private int getContactCount() {
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                return cursor.getCount();
            } else {
                cursor.close();
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private ContentObserver mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            new changeInContact().execute();
        }
    };

    public class changeInContact extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> arrayListContactID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int currentCount = getContactCount();
            // Add contact
            if (currentCount > mContactCount) {
                // Adding the contact if max contact id from device to sqlite database
            } else if (currentCount < mContactCount) {  
                // Delete contact from sqlite database which is not available in device
            } else if (currentCount == mContactCount) {
                // Check version of contact. If updated change info from device to sqlite
            }

            mContactCount = currentCount;
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

When my service is running in background i am getting error and my app crash. Error is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
at com.demo.example.ContactService$changeInContact.doInBackground(ContactService.java:577)
at com.demo.example.ContactService$changeInContact.doInBackground(ContactService.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
at com.demo.example.ContactService$changeInContact.doInBackground(ContactService.java:577)
at com.demo.example.ContactService$changeInContact.doInBackground(ContactService.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am not getting what is going wrong. Please suggest me with your valuable suggestions. I am struct due to this in my application very badly. Please suggest me with your opinion.

Comment: Whats at ContactService.java:577 ?

Comment: Why is onStartCommand inside the AsyncTask?

Comment: @iago: That was the typo mistake. onStart is out if Asynch task. Check the updates now.

Comment: @RohanKandwal The ContactService is my background service.

Comment: @ManojFegde Yes I know, I meant to say what's at ContactService line 577?

Comment: @RohanKandwal The code at line 577 is: String whereName = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?"; String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { dataIDofContact }; Cursor cursorContact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, null);

Comment: This error occurs when Selection Arguement is null, can you make sure that `dataIDofContact` isn't null everytime you are executing that particular query?

Comment: @RohanKandwal The DataId is null or not that i need to check. I will check it and update you.

Comment: @RohanKandwal: Thank you for your suggestion. It helps alot. I checked my code and get to know that my DataId is null.

Comment: @ManojFegde glad to be of help. I am posting my comment as an answer so you can mark this question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the bind value` is nothing but the `selectionArgs` of the `query`. If `selectionArgs` is null at any point, you will recieve this error when firing a `query`.